# Webpage loses interactivity with JavaScript when a form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a single page website that has three buttons (styled with jQuery Mobile) as a menu which, when clicked, show different content that is contained on hidden "div". However, on the main page I have a form connected to mysql which lets users join in, but when you fill the form and click the button "submit", the page "kind of reloads" and the header buttons don't work anymore. So, when form is submitted on main div, menu stops to work (it doesn't display and hide content anymore)  Is there any solution to this?
(I've included a snippet but here the problem is not seen as I can't connect it to mysql).

```js
function updateContent(hash) {

  var newClass = hash.substring(1);

  var newContent = $("." + newClass).html();


  $("#content").html(newContent);
  $("#content").css("display", "none");

}

if (window.location.hash) {

  updateContent(window.location.hash);

}

$(".contentUpdate").click(function() {

  updateContent($(this).attr("id"));
  $("#content").fadeIn();
  $(".contentUpdate").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
});
```

```css
.hiddenContent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="contentUpdate" id="#swim">Swim</a></li>
      <li><a class="contentUpdate" id="#cycle">Cycle</a></li>
      <li><a class="contentUpdate" id="#run">Run</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /navbar -->

</div>

<div id="content">

  FORM

  <div id="joinForm">
    <form method="post">

      <label for="name">Name and Surname(s)</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Adam Smith" value="" name="name" />

      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="example@esade.edu" value="" name="email" />

      <label for="phone">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="+34 671 542 893" value="" name="phone" />

      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <p>Choose the sports you're interested in:</p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="swimming" name="swimming" value="" />
        <label for="swimming">Swimming</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cycling" name="cycling" value="" />
        <label for="cycling">Cycling</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="running" name="running" value="" />      <label for="running">Running</label>
      </fieldset>

      <div align="right">
        <button type="submit" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>




<div class="hiddenContent swim">


  swim

</div>




<div class="hiddenContent cycle">

  cycle

</div>

<div class="hiddenContent run">

  run

</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want the page to reload, you need to use either aJax, fetch, or even webSockets to send the data.  Also you would then want to use preventDefault on the form to stop it reloading.

Comment: You are using a button type="submit" and form method = "post" so surely it will reload the page when you click on the submit button. So ajax call for saving data to MySQL  would be better as @Keith suggested